# How to remove Scrollbar in ChromeDriver, how to change http-agent?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use `IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options)` in C#

When I take `.GetScreenshot();`, often see scrollbar, is there a way to remove it?

2nd question, how to mock/change `http_agent` in ChromeDriver?

Answer (score 8):

Scrollbar issue:

- Try using Chrome switches when starting webdriver. See
  http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ or
  `chrome://flags/` in Chrome.
- You can also make Chromedriver open the
  url in a popup without scrollbars. You can do this using some
  Javascript.
- Or you could create a `user_data/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css` similar to the one below and launch Chrome with {--user-data-dir=user_data}

Custom.css:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #999999;
  display: none;
}

html > ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #999999;
  display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background-color: #797979;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: FYI, --hide-scrollbars worked for me. The Custom.css did not. Thanks for the post.

Comment: Same, the `--hide-scrollbars` worked for me as well.  Here is how to add the flag/switch: `ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); options.AddArgument("--hide-scrollbars");`

Answer (score 5):

as [Chuen Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1909629/chuen-lee) said:

Same, the `--hide-scrollbars` worked for me as well.

Here is how to add the flag/switch:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); options.AddArgument("--hide-scrollbars");
```