# Removing scrollbar from Selenium Screenshots

Tags: javascript, c#, css, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting screenshots of webpages using Chromedriver. My code works well.
I'm now attempting to remove the ugly scrollbars. Would it be possible to inject CSS into the page? I have seen a couple of [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449562/how-to-remove-scrollbar-in-chromedriver-how-to-change-http-agent), which do hint that this is possible ("*You can also make Chromedriver open the url in a popup without scrollbars. You can do this using some Javascript.*") but doesn't **show** how this is possible.

Has anybody got any idea as to how to do this?

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1100, 1100);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com/");
Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();

//Temp Img
string screenshot = ss.AsBase64EncodedString;
byte[] screenshotAsByteArray = ss.AsByteArray;
ss.SaveAsFile(fileNameTemp, ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg); 
ss.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // Create a driver instance for chromedriver
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver; 
    driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1100, 1100);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(hehe[i]);
    js.ExecuteScript("return document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';");
```

This worked!

Comment: And 'visible to put them back ie: object.style.overflow = "visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit"